# Inventory system for a text based adventure game in Java

Tags: java, inventory

I'm making a text based adventure game in Java. I need to give the user the ability to pick up items and put them in an inventory, but I'm not really sure how!

This is how my items are currently set up:

```
Items item0 = new Items(0);
    item0.setName("Map");


    Items item1 = new Items(1);
    item1.setName("Sword");

    Items[] itemize  = new Items[2];
    itemize[0] = item0;
    itemize[1] = item1;
```

I need to be able to have specific items in certain rooms. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to store each group of items in separate data structure. Or alternatively you can give each `Item` an attribute which would specify its group and when displaying item from a certain group you will take into consideration only items with given group.

Comment: Can you post the `Items` code?

Answer (score 2):

Java lovers! I am posting a code that I quickly created regarding the ability to keep track of a players inventory in Java during a text adventure. There are many other uses for this type of code (as experts know), but today I decided to help out the beginners and post this code for critique and use in a text adventure if you are having trouble. This is not a tutorial on how to make a text adventure, only add an inventory function. So here we go:

First thing we need to do is import the necessary pre-requisites:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Obviously, the scanner will already be imported. Next, we have to create the list:

```
List<String> inv = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The "List" function creates a new list. This will store all data for the inventory; I called my list 'inv'. Now we have our first action! Mine is hypothetical (remember), but you can do whatever you'd like.

```
System.out.println("You see a rusty axe on the floor next to a can of pepsi.");
choice = scan.nextLine();
```

This is a very simple "scan for input" kind of code. Nothing new, I assume. Now comes the fun part:

```
if (choice.equals("take axe")) {
    System.out.println("You pick up the axe");
    inv.add("axe");
```

Did you see that there? We just added the axe to the players inventory! It's that simple. We can display the inventory now using:

```
System.out.println(inv);
```

Done! Now for using up an item. I will use a different example where the player picked up the pepsi:

```
System.out.println("You walk for awhile and start to become thirsty");
System.out.println(inv);
choice = scan.nextLine();
```

We print the inventory so the player knows what is available to use. Now watch this:

```
if (choice.equals("drink")) {
    if (inv.contains("pepsi")) {
        System.out.println("You drink a can of pepsi");
        inv.remove("pepsi");
```

Thats right! All we do is use the remove function. But now let's say the player decided NOT to take the pepsi. We are going to make an 'else if' to the previous if statement:

```
if (inv.contains("pepsi")) {
    System.out.println("You drank pepsi");
    inv.remove("pepsi");
} else if (!inv.contains("pepsi")) {
    System.out.println("You have nothing to drink!");
}
```

Awesome! All we did was put an exclamation mark (meaning opposite) in front of the conditional statement. If you don't understand, check out down below.

Anyways, glad I could help you out (there is a reason it is called easy inventory!). If you have any questions, reply asking whatever you wish (even if it's for me to make another tutorial). Leave feedback if this was no use to you (because you already know what you're doing) and tell me how to get better. Thanks!